# Is there a stack tracing tool for printing sequence of variable values in Python?

Tags: python, debugging

I'd like to find out the local/global variables used in a python script and the values they take. I won't be able to use any graphical user interface or even anything which requires us to manually watch values of variables. 
For example, for the given code-

```
def iterPower(base, exp):
    r=1
    for k in xrange(exp):
        r=r*base
    return r
iterPower(5.0, 3)
```

The tracing/debugging program should be able to print this:

```
base = 5.0
exp = 3
r=1, 5.0, 25.0, 125.0
```

I looked into [Hunter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hunter) and [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) but I cant really make out if they can do any such thing. Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can certainly use `pdb` to step through your code and print out the value of variables at any point.  There are lots of articles out there to get you started with `pdb`.

Comment: the point is I want this process to be automated, thus, we should be able to automatically see the values of variables assigned to them throughout the execution.

Comment: You can make hunter make that printout with this eye-popping one liner: `hunter.trace(action=lambda event, collector=defaultdict(list): [collector[k].append(v) if v not in collector[k] else None for k, v in event.locals.items()] and [print(f'{k}={", ".join(map(str, v))}') for k, v in collector.items()])`.

Btw, you're more than welcome to ask questions in hunter's issue tracker.